# How to use nested generic types in Scala as method return type

Tags: scala, generics

I have a few methods that would like to use a nested generic type as its return type.

```
import scala.language.higherKinds

trait DBClient {
  def execute[T[U] <: DataStoreItem[U]](ops: ScanamoOps[Result[T]]): Future[U]
}
```

But this doesn't work. I am not able to use `U` in my return Type. Is there any other way to define a method like the one above where I can use a nested type `U` in my return type.

I also Tried:

```
trait DBClient {
  def execute[U, T <: DataStoreItem[U]](ops: ScanamoOps[Result[T]]): Future[U]
}
```

Which doesn't work either. Thanks for helping, I am very new to scala generics and higher order types. So please excuse my ignorance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it almost right.

```
import scala.language.higherKinds

trait DBClient {
  def execute[T[U0] <: DataStoreItem[U0], U](ops: ScanamoOps[Result[T[U]]]): Future[U]
}
```

Comment: Actually `def execute[T[_] <: DataStoreItem[_], U]` is not the same as `def execute[T[U0] <: DataStoreItem[U0], U]`. In the latter case you declare a type constructor `T[_]` such that for every `U0`, `T[U0]` is a subtype of `DataStoreItem[U0]`. In the former case you declare a type constructor `T[_]` such that for every `U0`, `T[U0]` is a subtype of the existential type `DataStoreItem[_]` (`DataStoreItem[U1] forSome { type U1 }`).